# Show author on every sub-page

Tags: plugins, pages, page-template, author

Is it possible to display the author on all pages (not blog-entries) who created it? Every plugin I find is for blog-posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following code to content-page.php in your theme folder.

```
<?php the_author(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly you should be able to edit your page template to include the below. I'm not sure on any plugin to do this though.

More info: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author

```
 <?php $author = get_the_author(); echo "$author"; ?>
```

** This is untested